# Fatal Error with PhP on submit

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm making a form where I can add records to a database through the browser. When I press submit, it comes up with this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in
>   /srv/http/career.php on line 56

Line 56 is based of this PhP line:

```
$result->execute($_POST);
```

It's not related to the connection of the database, that works because I am able to view already made records.

Full code

HTML

```
<form method="POST">
    <label for="jobtitle">Job Title</label> <input type="text" name="jobtitle" /> <br>
    <label for="reference">Reference</label> <input type="text" name="reference" /> <br>
    <label for="salary">Salary</label> <input type="text" name="salary"/> <br>
    <label for="location">Location</label> <input type="text" name="location"/> <br> <br>
    <label for="description">Description</label> <input type="text" name="description"/> <br> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

PhP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['jobtitle'],$_POST['reference'],$_POST['salary'],$_POST['location'],$_POST['description'])){
    $result= $pdo->query('INSERT INTO jobs (job_title, job_ref, job_salary, job_location, job_desc)
        VALUES ("' . $_POST['jobtitle'] . '","' . $_POST['reference'] . '","' . $_POST['location'] . '","' . $_POST['description'] .'")');
        unset($_POST['submit']); 

    $result->execute($_POST);
}
?>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why do you call it "PhP" ? :D

Comment: I like the way it looks, I should really stop tbh @CodeiSir

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you execute($_POST)?

Comment: PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement object, or FALSE on failure.

Comment: If `$result` is a boolean, then your `query()` returned false; it failed.

Comment: @durbnpoisn for it to create a record onto the database. The text fields are for data input

Comment: ^--- =>>> http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: ^--- =>>> http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `query()` and concatenating values into your SQL string, try using a prepared statement like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO jobs (job_title, job_ref, job_salary, 
                       job_location, job_desc) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
$stmt->bindValue(1, $_POST['jobtitle']);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $_POST['reference']);
$stmt->bindValue(3, $_POST['salary']);
$stmt->bindValue(4, $_POST['location']);
$stmt->bindValue(5, $_POST['description']);
$stmt->execute();
```

There are many benefits to this approach, including making it easier to tell when you're missing one of the values you are trying to insert (salary).